# How to prove if $m$, $m + 2$, $m + 4$ are all primes, then $m = 3$

Tags: prime-numbers, proof-writing, congruences

I feel as though I have to use mods, but I'm not sure how exactly to go about this one.

Comment: Probably consider the three modulo $3$.

Comment: Hint:  if $m>3$ is a prime then either $m=3k+1$ or $m=3k+2$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that result.

Comment: @lulu, can you link me to a proof of that result? Google seems to yield very little

Comment: It follows from the division algorithm with remainder.  Take an integer $n$ and divide it by $3$; it leaves a remainder of $0$,$1$, or $2$.  Now in your case, if we take $m$ prime and greater than $3$ it can't be divisible by $3$ so the remainder must be $1$ or $2$.

Comment: @lulu thank you so much! That really helps! :)

Comment: With that result, it seems pretty easy! By contradiction, assume m =/ 3. 
Then either m is 2, or m>3. If m=2, 2+2=4 which is not prime.
If m>3, by using the result, in either case I can arrange a factor to be either 3(k+1) or 3(k+2), neither of which are prime, as they are divisible by 3, and by our assumption m =/ 3.

Thank you so much for that hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *have* to use mods but they do make things much simpler.

Suppose $m$ is a positive prime other than 3. Then $m \equiv 1$ or $2 \pmod 3$. In the former case, $m + 2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ so it's clearly composite. In the latter case, $m + 4 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, so again we have a composite.

This leaves $m \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ as the only viable possibility, but then $m$ has to be 3 in order to be prime.

Alternatively you can do things "algebraically": instead of $m \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ you say $m = 3k + 1$, for example.

Comment: the algebraic route is what I wound up doing! 
thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can show that one of them must be divisible by $3$.  If it is not $3$, it is not prime.

Comment: How exactly would I go about doing that? Please forgive my ignorance

Comment: $m$ can be $0,1,2 \pmod 3$.  You can just try them all and note that one of $m,m+2,m+4$ is $0 \pmod 3$ in any case.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$m(m+2)(m+4)=m^3+6m^2+8m=6m^2+9m+m^3-m\\=3(2m^2+3m)+(m-1)m(m+1)$$

Now among any three consecutive integers, one is divisible by $3$...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the benefit of multiplying them all as such. Why did you choose to do that?

Comment: @JohnL. Because $3$ is a prime, if it divides a product it must divide one of the terms. If you have a list of numbers and you want to show that a PRIME divides at least one of them, it is enough to prove that the prime divides their product. This way you only need to work with the product (which is one number) instead of dealing with every one of the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

One of the three numbers $n$, $n+2$, $n+4$ has to be a multiple of $3$.  And only one prime is a multiple of $3$.